# Distorted characters in ie9 printing

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-9

When printing our website's page from ie9, certain characters are consistently distorting themselves like so (should say "301 results"):

[image: Distorted Characters]

Capital B's, S's, and 8's are also uniformly distorted. I've found fixes for garbled and nonsense text, but fixing this sort of distortion is eluding me. Also, everything prints perfectly from Chrome, so it's not an issue with the printer.

We're using Angular on a Ruby on Rails base, if that matters.